# Do git tags work recursively on submodules?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have created a submodule in  my git repository (`repo1`) by the following command `git submodule add https://github.com/user/mod1`. So after adding this command, my repo now contains the sudmodule `mod1`.

Now I am applying a tag to my repository `repo` using command - `git tag -a baseline -m "tagging baseline code`.

I am not sure if this tag will also be applied to the submodule `mod1`? When I create a new clone recursively and with specific tag, will I get all the code (including submodule) with the tag I am specifying?

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: I did and I did not see the tag added at the parent repo level getting applied to the submodule. I then ended up tagging my submodule (which is also a git repo by itself) independently.

Comment: Well there you go, then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not sure if this tag will also be applied to the submodule mod1

Submodule by definition

> ***`Submodules`*** ***allow foreign repositories to be embedded within a dedicated subdirectory*** of the source tree, always pointed at a particular commit.

---

If you will tag your project the tag **will not** apply to the submodule as well.

By default the new submodule will be tracking [HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location/34519716#34519716) of the master branch but will NOT be updated as you update your primary repo.

Answer (score 0):

`git` handles submodules by storing the ID of a submodule commit (as part of main repository commit's content), which is checked out after the submodule is initialized. So while, by tagging, you indirectly associate the tag with the current submodule commit ID — in the context of the main repository, you don't add the actual tag to the submodule.